# How to parametrise unit tests for sklearn models

Tags: python, unit-testing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I want to create some unit tests to make sure the correct `NotImplemented` exceptions are thrown for a module I am developing. Is there a way that I could use some dummy data, create and fit multiple `sklearn` models to feed into the unit tests?

I'm looking for a parametric solution, that in some way I could go through many models instead of manually defining each different model. I do not need well-defined models, or models that make sense, just models that can be constructed with their default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pytest` methods for fixtures and test parameterization are one way to approach this. Here's an example using [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) to assert that two ensemble methods can perfectly predict their training data:

```py
# File: `test_ml_models.py`
import pytest
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier


@pytest.mark.parametrize("model", [RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("X", [np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [np.array([0, 1])])
def test_models(model, X, y):
    clf = model().fit(X, y)
    assert np.all(clf.predict(X) == y)
```

Then running `pytest` shows our `test_models` test was unfolded into two tests:

```bash
$ pytest test_ml_models.py
=================================== test session starts ==============
platform linux -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/hayesall
plugins: anyio-3.3.0, dash-1.20.0, cov-2.12.1
collected 2 items

test_ml_models.py ..                                            [100%]

=================================== 2 passed in 0.59s ================
```

For further reading, you might skim how `scikit-learn` or `imbalanced-learn` approach unit testing:

- [`imbalanced-learn: test_easy_ensemble.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/7cead9c29e8e72450302ca710643bc471f31016f/imblearn/ensemble/tests/test_easy_ensemble.py)
- [`scikit-learn: test_forest.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/12176efa867a066032883733aa115fd31db5ee8a/sklearn/ensemble/tests/test_forest.py)